# Nginx resolves only base URL

Tags: node.js, nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I'm new in Nginx. What I'm trying to do is to pair it with my NodeJS backend server.

My Nginx resolves successfully only **mydomain.com** but not **mydomain.com/some_path**.

Here I try to access **mydomain.com**

[image]

And here **mydomain.com/metadata**

[image]

This is my Nginx default file (/etc/nginx/sites-available/default):

[image]

What am I doing wrong with it?

How to make Nginx redirect **mydomain.com/some/random/path?with=some&query=asd** to **127.0.0.1:4300/some/random/path?with=some&query=asd**

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is very simple. I had to remove **try_files $uri $uri/ =404**.

Now everything works just fine!